# Ubuntu 18.04 can't write on NTFS partition

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs

I have a dual boot (windows  10 and Ubuntu 18.04) laptop. I wan to keep a separate partition common to both operating systems.

I formatted that partition as NTFS form windows, Then I could only read it from Ubuntu. I could not write on it.
Then I formatted it Using Ubuntu. After that I could read and write using Ubuntu. Later, I saved some file on it using windows. Then after I got the same problem. Now I cant write on it using Ubuntu.

I reinstalled ntfs-3g, but could not solve the problem. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: If you search AskUbuntu for "ntfs read only" there are quite a few entries about this problem.  Many of them suggest that the disk is considered 'dirty' and the fix is to tun `chkdsk` in Windows.  Another common problem is that Windows fastboot is still enabled (which will result in 'dirty' disks).  The Linux implementation of NTFS is not superb and fixing problems with ntfs disks, and Windows utilities should be used if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your windows is putting the "read-only" flag on all detectable ntfs partitions everytime it shuts down or reboots.

If you don't want it to do that, boot to your windows, open up a administator powershell (to do that find powershell in start, right click on it, then select "run as Administrator").

then type :

```
powercfg -h off
```

Comment: Disabling hibernation solved the problem.

Comment: hibernation on windows is still possible after that BTW. this only makes "hyper boot" impossible on windows.

Comment: if you don't want to use the command as @tatsu mentioned, you can turn off the fast startup mode by using the Power Options in Control Panel.

Comment: @tatsu Can you tell me please how is hibernation still possible on Windows? Because the option isn't in the power menu anymore, and it's not available in the power settings as before running this command.

Comment: well do you really need that? you can sleep the computer instead of hibernating it. in any case if you ubuntu install completed successfully you can re-enable it with `powercfg -h on` or with a windows update (you'll also need to reboot in both cases).

Comment: It's on rare occasions, but yeah I need it sometimes. I tried `powercfg -h on`, but I couldn't write on the ntfs partitions again. But it's okay as I can just enable it when I need hibernation and disable it when I'm done with it. Thanks.